# Travis CI Trigger Build option on repo unabled

Tags: travis-ci

I'm working on my first [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/) project. I'm not sure how it works yet. 
The thing is when I try to configure **trigger builds** ([Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTVIy.png)), option appears as *not allowed*, it doesn't let me click it. 
And this is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
cache:
  directories:
    - ~/.npm
node_js:
  - '12'
git:
  depth: 3
script:
  - yarn build
deploy:
  provider: pages
  edge: true
  skip-cleanup: true
  keep-history: true
  github-token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  local-dir: dist/
  target-branch: gh-pages
  commit_message: "Deploy Release"
  on:
    branch: main
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to confirm your account with the email that Travis CI is sent to you?

With the new feature of Travis CI, you will need to confirm your account once your sign up for travis-ci.com. To confirm you get an email that is attached to your GitHub accounts. After confirmation, you will be able to see the "Trigger Build" option visible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30017665)

Comment: @JuanSturla added a wider explanation. Thanks.